# Why is it “lire la vidéo” instead of ouvrir or regarder?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, informatique

I set my phone to French and I saw it says “lire la vidéo” on Instagram and also on YouTube it says “La vidéo sera lue après cette annonce”. Why is that?

Comment: Je pense qu'à une époque on disait *jouer un disque*, mais qu'ensuite on est passés à *lire une cassette*, et c'est toujours le cas avec la vidéo. Si quelqu'un trouve plus d'infos là dessus, ce serait intéressant.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Au TLFi on trouve jouer avec radio comme sujet ou familièrement faire jouer le phono ; mais je sais qu'on dit aussi que tel musique/artiste _joue à la radio_. C'est l'idée pour un appareil de _reproduire ou retransmettre de la musique préalablement enregistrée_ (TLFi). Pour _interpréter_ il y a des hésitations entre transitif direct et indirect. Pour _lire_ t'avais déjà des spécialisations avec l'idée du déchiffrement musical ou du dessin au 18e. L'influence du _lecteur_ pour _l'instrument servant à reproduire des sons enregistrés_ (1934) a peut-être été déterminante ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Peut-être faire une question avec ça. On peut aussi dire _faire jouer un film_ que je sache etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is clear; in American the term that describes the action of a program that consists in opening a file and making its content available is "to read"; the French computer engineers translated literally and as what you do in order to listen or to watch something is to give to the machine an instruction to read a file, you get the same term.

[read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reading_(computer))

Reading is an action performed by computers, to acquire data from a source and place it into their volatile memory for processing. Computers may read information from a variety of sources, such as magnetic storage, the Internet, or audio and video input ports. Reading is one of the core functions of a Turing machine.

Comment: That's at least missing a source and likely wrong. User interface text on phones as well as YouTube is written in English first, usually in this case with the verb "to play a video", then translated into French by professional translators (rather than "computer engineers") who have can pretty much choose which term to use to translate "play". I don't see how this could be carrying over from the computer science term "to read a file".

Comment: @qoba It seems to me that essentially one trend is responsible for this state of affairs and that's the way the sofware concept ass been named initially (read); let's concede that accessory trends have come into being and that this scheme has been adulterated somewhat as time went by and that  the influence of others than the sofware engineers has come to change things a bit; let's not forget though that the translators **are** the sofware engineers: there are numerous instances of people in that category asking for advice on the FSE; (field 1)

Comment: @qoba they need to know which term they should choose for their programs according to existing practices of naming in the field: they are not professional translators and they are the ones who decide in the end; it was even more the initiative of those people in the early days of the net. Let's not forget that only the engineers know really the concepts to be named. Finally let's take the case of the VLC program, that you can use for playing mp3's, mp4's, and at the same time for displaying png's, jpg's, and others; (field 2)

Comment: @qoba  for whatever medium (strictly image, strictly sound or video) the terms are "lecture" and "lire". (end)

Comment: sorry this made no sense to me

Answer (score 10):

Il faut savoir qu'en français, une *playlist* est une [liste de lecture](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/liste_de_lecture) ; qu'un *multimedia player* est un [lecteur multimédia](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8354113) (par exemple, le lecteur VLC « est capable de lire un grand nombre de flux réseaux » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player)) ; que le *streaming* fait référence au (en) flux et à lecture en continu (voir [GDT](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2075185), [Franceterme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=streaming&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search), [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=LECTURE%20VIDEO%20CONTINU&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_flux)) ; que dans le domaine de l'audiovisuel la *lecture* désigne la « restitution, par un lecteur, de signaux enregistrés sous forme numérique, mécanique, magnétique ou optique » ([Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/lecture_nf/46547?q=lecture#46468)) et que le *lecteur des sons*, l'« instrument servant à reproduire des sons enregistrés » (DHLF) est [attesté](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/lecteur/0) en 1934, bien avant toute notion d'informatique moderne ; qu'on a eu toute une lignée de [lecteurs](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lecteur/0) ou d'appareils qui lisent ou font la lecture de signaux ou d'informations, dont le lecteur de cassettes audio, VHS (voire Betamax), le lecteur (de) diques compacts/CD, DVD, Blu-ray etc. ; que la fonction *playback* peut être traduite par lecture ([Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/playback/602522)) ; que l'aide en français de Youtube parle, entre autres, de [*lire des vidéos*](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3037019?hl=fr&ref_topic=9257580) ; que l'aide d'Instagram parle, entre autres, d'un bouton « [*lire la vidéo*](https://fr-fr.facebook.com/help/instagram/640455899468439?helpref=search&sr=1&query=lire%20vid%C3%A9o) ». Inutile de rappeler que la [*lecture*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lecture) est l'action de lire.

Évidemment on peut *regarder, visionner* un/une vidéo mais le lecteur multimédia/vidéo fait la lecture ou lit un fichier multimédia dont le contenu s'affiche, et donc l'emploi du terme *lecture* et du verbe *lire* est dans l'ordre des choses et s'intègre parfaitement à la terminologie établie depuis un bon moment en français, où ces termes sont possiblement davantage utilisés qu'en langue anglaise.

---

In so many words because it's absolutely proper French and the verb *lire* is the action pertaining to the noun *lecture* done by the *lecteur* tool, all of which form a wide variety of terms used in the field of audio&video, including before modern IT.

Comment: En plus du lecteur multimédia, on peut citer le lecteur de cassettes audio ou VHS, lecteur de DVD, lecteur de CD comme des prédécesseurs. L'idée étant généralement de lire une vidéo provenant d'un support où elle a été enregistrée.

Comment: @qoba Merci, j'ai ajouté ça, ça permet de faire le lien entre la lecture qui était définie et ses applications sous forme d'appareils. Au début je voulais rester dans le domaine logiciel vu la question. Mais on glisse tranquillement vers l'origine et la raison, l'étymologie avec en arrière-plan l'interrogation de Stéphane sous la question. J'aimerais pouvoir répondre à la totale mais l'important surtout c'est selon moi d'illustrer la continuité au lexique et l'importance du terme en question. Une question sur la transition le cas échéant entre jouer et lire serait bien pour aller plus loin.